# Cannot --enable-pcregrep-libbz2 because bzlib.h was not found

Tags: linux, fedora, pcre, yum

I am trying to install pcre 8.32.
 When I tried to install following this [tutorial](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/pcre.html) I get this error:

```
 **Cannot --enable-pcregrep-libbz2 because bzlib.h was not found**.
```

Then I tried: `sudo yum  install libbz2-dev` and now it is saying `No package libbz2-dev available.Error: Nothing to do`

I am totally confused. What shold I do next?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try to locate the package that provides the `bzlib.h` file with:

```
sudo yum whatprovides */bzlib.h
```

And then install that package

From your comment the package name is `bzip2-devel-1.0.6-3.fc15.i686`, so do:

```
sudo yum install bzip2-devel-1.0.6-3.fc15.i686
```

Comment: I tried that command and it says `Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
bzip2-devel-1.0.6-3.fc15.i686 : Header files developing apps which will use
                              : bzip2
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/bzlib.h
` etc . But when I again tried to install pcre, result is same !

Comment: Thanks a lot. But one more problem. its now saying `** Cannot --enable-pcregrep-libbz2 because libbz2 was not found`. What should I do now? Thanks again

Comment: Ok I installed bzip2 and the problem solved! Thanks Atropo !

Comment: Pay attention to architecture: the `i686` in `bzip2-devel-1.0.6-3.fc15.i686`.  The `sudo yum whatprovides` can return more than one package, for instance, `bzip2-devel-1.0.6-3.fc15.x86_64`.

Comment: Didn't know about `yum whatprovides`. Nice trick!