# ** Cannot --enable-pcregrep-libz because zlib.h was not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pcre

I'm trying to install pcre-8.35 on Ubuntu. My issue is similar to [this guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969513/cannot-enable-pcregrep-libbz2-because-bzlib-h-was-not-found/).
I'm following the same tutorial, but my problem stems from a command up from his.When I try to install, I receive this error message:
`** Cannot --enable-pcregrep-libz because zlib.h was not found`
I did some research and ran this command:
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall zlib1g`
But, I still have the same problem. Help is appreciated!

Comment: What does say `dpkg -S zlib.h` ?

Comment: This is an off-topic question here, but `zlib1g-dev` is the package you want. Library packages typically just come with the libraries, you need the development packages if you want the headers and such as well.

Comment: Thank you Paul, and I won't post a Linux related question again. Can you help me with another problem that arose? I'm following the instructions for the problem that the other guy had and when I run the yum whatprovides command, no matches return. Does this mean the file I'm looking for isn't on my machine. How do I fix that? What yum repositories do I need to enable? Sorry for all the questions. I'm just beginning to learn Linux.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to solve this issue `Cannot --enable-pcregrep-libz because zlib.h was not found` with just this command:

`sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev`

It's like the tip given by [Paul Griffiths](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2399879/paul-griffiths)